# Conditionally-grouping from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of people with their preferred games to play (in the exact same format as in the picture attached).
I wish to create new lists corresponding to the number of games, with each list specifying the relevant people - see example with the "basketball group" in the picture attached.
How can it be done using conditional statements?
I'd like to have an implementation if possible, I'm a bit confused.
Thanks.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBDab.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

When using Office 365 you could use `FILTER()` in combination with `FIND()`:
`=FILTER($A$2:$A$5,ISNUMBER(FIND(LEFT(F$1,LEN(F$1)-LEN(" group")),$B$2:$B$5)))`

[image]